# Primitive polynomials in LFSRs

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, random, cryptography

I need help proving the following theorem. I found it many books but on every single one it says that they omit the proof because it is in every good textbook.

THM
Let $c(x)$ be a connection (characteristic) polynomial of an LFSR of length $n$. Then  $c(x)$ is primitive polynomial iff every non-zero initial state of an LFSR produces a pseudorandom sequence of length $2^n-1$.

Comment: The proof can be written up in a variety of different ways depending on what one assumes is known already and what definition of "primitive polynomial" one uses. For example, one _definition_ of primitive polynomial, most likely unacceptable to mathematically minded folks but commonly used by engineers such as myself is that a degree-$n$ irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_2[x]$ is called a primitive polynomial if and only if the corresponding LFSR produces a sequence of period $2^n-1$ from every nonzero initial state.

Comment: My apologies for not specifing exact definition of primitive polynomial assumed, but as a mathematically minded guy I was unaware that there exist any different from the following: $f$ is primitive if it is irreducible in $F_{2}[x]$ and there exists a root of $f$ that generates $F_{2^n}$

Comment: I assume you meant to write $\mathbb F_{2^n}^\times$ and not $\mathbb F_{2^n}$. The root of $f$ generates the multiplicative group of the field, not the entire field.

Comment: Yes Sir, I meant the multiplicative group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definition: A primitive polynomial $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial 
of degree $n$ in 
$\mathbb F_{2^n}[x]$ with the property that each root of $f$ is a generator
of $\mathbb F_{2^n}^\times$, the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{2^n}$.

Let $\alpha$ denote a root of the primitive
polynomial $$f(x) = f_0 + f_1x + \cdots + f_n x^n = 1 + f_1 x + \cdots + f_{n-1}x^{n-1} + x^n$$
Consider any initial nonzero loading
$(s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{n-1})$ of the *linear feedback shift register* (LFSR).
Note that the $s_i \in \mathbb F_2$ and at least one $s_i$ is nonzero.
The first output bit from the register is $s_0$ while the first bit *fed back*
into the register is 
$$s_n = s_0 + f_{n-1}s_1 + f_{n-2}s_2 + \cdots + f_1s_{n-1}. \tag{1}$$
The next shift register contents are $(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)$.  More generally,
the contents of the shift register are $(s_m, s_{m+1}, \ldots, s_{m+n-1})$,
the bit $s_m$ is the output, the bit
$$s_{m+n} = s_m + f_{n-1}s_{m+1} + f_{n-2}s_{m+2} + \cdots + f_1s_{m+n-1}\tag{2}$$
is fed back into the register thus making the contents
$(s_{m+1}, s_{m+w}, \ldots, s_{m+n})$.

Now, since $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$, we have that for any nonzero 
$\beta \in \mathbb F_{2^n}$
$$0= \beta f(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^n f_k \beta \alpha^k$$
Since the *conjugates* $\alpha^2$, $\alpha^{2^2}, \cdots,\alpha^{2^i},\cdots,  \alpha^{2^{n-1}}$ 
of $\alpha$ also are roots of $f(x)$, we have similarly (using $\beta^{2^i}$ with
$\alpha^{2^i}$) that
$$\begin{align} 0 &= \beta^{2^i}f\left(\alpha^{2^i}\right) 
= \sum_{k=0}^n f_k \beta^{2^i} \left(\alpha^{2^i}\right)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^n f_k \beta^{2^i} \left(\alpha^k\right)^{2^i}
= \sum_{k=0}^n f_k \left(\beta\alpha^k\right)^{2^i}, & 0 \leq i \leq n-1.
\end{align}$$
Adding these $n$ equations and remembering that the *trace*
of $y$: $\operatorname{Tr}(y) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} y^{2^i}$
is a homomorphism from $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ to $\mathbb F_2$,
we have that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n f_k \operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^k) = 
\operatorname{Tr}(\beta) + f_1\operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha)
+ \cdots + f_{n-1}\operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^{n-1}) 
+ \operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^n) = 0 \tag{3}$$ where
the $\operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^k) \in \mathbb F_2$.
Now, for each $\beta \in \mathbb F_{2^n}$, 
$(\operatorname{Tr}(\beta), \operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha),
\ldots, \operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^{n-1}))$ is the
*representation* of $\beta$ with respect to the *dual*
of the *standard polynomial basis* $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, 
\alpha^{n-1}\}$.
Thus, the *initial* nonzero loading $(s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{n-1})$
of the shift register can be viewed as the dual-basis
representation of *some* nonzero $\beta \in \mathbb F_{2^n}$.
Comparing $(1)$ and $(3)$, we see that the *next* shift-register
contents are 
$$(s_1, \ldots, s_{n-1}, s_n) 
= (\operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha), \operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^2),
\ldots, \operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha^{n}))
= (\operatorname{Tr}(\beta\alpha), \operatorname{Tr}((\beta\alpha)\cdot\alpha),
\ldots, \operatorname{Tr}((\beta\alpha)\cdot\alpha^{n-1})),$$
that is,
*the representation of $\beta\alpha$ with respect to the dual of the
standard polynomial basis.*

> Thus, we can consider the shift register as containing,
>   *in succession*, the elements $\beta, \beta\alpha, \beta\alpha^2, \ldots$
>   (all represented with respect to the dual basis of the standard
>   polynomial basis).
>   Since $\alpha$ is of multiplicative order $2^n-1$, the shift
>   register contents repeat periodically with a period of $2^n-1$,
>   and so does the output sequence $s_0, s_1, \ldots$ repeat periodically
>   with a period of $2^n-1$.

---

OK, that shows that $f(x)$ being a primitive polynomial gives 
an output sequence of period $2^n-1$. The proof in the reverse direction 
is left for you as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you think I could bother you for a hint for the converse? Just a general one, if it uses any results of the sort of basis duality here, and style of the proof (direct, contradiction). Producing this proof is an urgent matter for me.

Comment: Hint: the succession of $n$-tuple contents are obtained by successive applications of a _linear_ transformation: $L :\mathbb F_2^n \to \mathbb F_2^n$ whose characteristic polynomial $f(x)$ is a divisor of $x^{2^n-1}-1$ but not a divisor of any $x^k-1$ where $1 \leq k < 2^n-1$. So the roots of $f(x)$, which are in $\mathbb F_{2^n}$, must have multiplicative order $2^n-1$